# Is it possible to query with IN expression in Doctrine, with multiple InParameter as arguments?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a query whose structure is similar to the one provided in the MySQL Docs page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in

```sql
SELECT (3,4) IN ((1,2), (3,4));
```

My query looks like this

```sql
SELECT e
FROM CalendarEvent e
WHERE (e.id, e.start) NOT IN (
    SELECT se.masterEventId, se.originalStartDate
    FROM CalendarEvent se
    WHERE se.originalStartDate IS NOT NULL
)
```

Except that I get the following exception:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 659: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

Is this not supported by Doctrine? If so, what workaround could I use in this case?

Comment: What do you mean your `query looks like` ? can you post your php code please ? at least your DQL statement

Comment: @VincentDecaux I've updated the query in the question. Does this bring more clarity?

Comment: Meanwhile I've moved along with the following solution 
```SELECT e
FROM CalendarEvent e
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT se.id
    FROM CalendarEvent se
    WHERE se.masterEventId = e.id AND se.originalStartDate = e.start
)
```
Not ideal, but it works for now.